# Tracking slow login items with OSX

Tags: macos, applications, login-items, mojave

I recently installed OSX Mojave beta and noticed that the login process is slower as the apps load.

I was wondering if there was a way to track the amount of time each app/process takes to load at startup to identify where the bottleneck is? Checking the console log doesn't really help.

I have no doubt that some of the apps loading at startup are not fully compatible with the new OS, but this issue could easily be happening on any version of OSX.

What is the best way to track apps that are loading slowly / creating a bottleneck in the bootup process?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your `syslog` with:

`tail -f /var/log/system.log`

You should see your login item process starting with a linked timestamp.
Console.app is more user-friendly if you don't like the terminal.

Other option, disable all your login items and then enable them one-by-one and you will see who is the bottleneck.